# How can I batch combine 'png images in gimp? ie one background image with many overlays?

Tags: gimp, gimpfu

I have an image that I need to combine with a large number of QR codes individually, and then save as a new image.  Is this possible to do using gimpfu or bimp?
The QR codes need to be positioned specifically and I am having issues trying to automate this process.
Right now my general, manual workflow is as such: Select, paste-into, rescale QR code, anchor, export.
Help??

Comment: i ended up using SG's combine/overlay script: http://gimpscripts.com/2011/10/combineoverlay-background/

Answer (score 0):

Use [ImageMagick's `compose`](http://www.imagemagick.org/Usage/compose/#compose) for this.

Comment: Thanks, I am investigating now. Are there any other resources or similar questions that would help me get the hang of applying Imagemagick to this sort of task?  I am new to this type of image processing workflow.